# Query no encuentra el elemento que contenga "Manzana"

Tags: mysql, c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Necesito imprimir por pantalla los elementos que contenga la palabra "Manzana" que se encuentra en mayusculas y minusculas

```
string[] ArrayPostres = { "Pie de Manzana", "Pie de Limon", "Chocolate con Manzana", "Mermelada de limon", "Mermelada de pina", "Mermelada de manzana", "Pie de pera" };
// Query Sintaxis
IEnumerable<string> PostresConManza =
    from i in ArrayPostres
    where ArrayPostres.Contains("Manzana")
    select i;

foreach (var item in PostresConManza)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
```

Pero mi variale `PostresConManza` nunca recibe ningun valor, siempre se mantiene en nulll,
si elimino la palabra `Manzana` de mi condicion `where`

```
where ArrayPostres.Contains("")
```

deberia listar todo el array, pero tampoco lo hace, a que se debe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` representa un elemento del arreglo y ese elemento debe contener la palabra Manzana así que el `where` debe quedar así:

```
where i.Contains("Manzana")
```